# I want to make a master macro file which runs macro code in the whichever file I select

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I want to make a master macro file which runs macro code in whichever file I select. The code only pulls out data and paste in the New sheet or particular selected file. Every time I have to open file and run macro. Is it possible to do without opening file?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a master macro file, one option is to make  use of a VB Script file with the content such as given below.

```
Option Explicit

On Error Resume Next

ExcelMacroExample

Sub ExcelMacroExample() 

  Dim xlApp 
  Dim xlBook 

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\abc.xlsm", 0, True) 
  xlApp.Run "TestMacro1"
  xlApp.Visible = True

  xlApp.Quit 

  Set xlBook = Nothing 
  Set xlApp = Nothing 

End Sub
```

Open Notepad, paste above code and save it something like `RunAbcMacro.vbs`.

Above code will open the macro file "D:\abc.xlsm" and run the macro named `TestMacro1`where TestMacro1 can be of the following, inside "D:\abc.xlsm".

```
Public Function TestMacro1() As Boolean
    MsgBox "InTestMacro1"
    TestMacro1 = True
End Function
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want that certain code is available in all your workbooks, then use your PERSONAL.XLS or in Excel 2007-2016 your PERSONAL.XLSB file.

See this URL for all details.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/personal.htm